# ValueError: too many values to unpack: error in django models while querying a model

Tags: python, django

The following is the stack trace-

```
Internal Server Error: /merger/merge/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Yash\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Yash\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\Yash\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "F:\Internship Project\pdf_merger\merger\views.py", line 72, in mergefiles
    mergedFile = requests.post('https://pdfmergerapi.herokuapp.com/', files = postlist)
  File "C:\Users\Yash\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 112, in post
    return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Yash\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 58, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Yash\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 494, in request
    prep = self.prepare_request(req)
  File "C:\Users\Yash\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 437, in prepare_request
    hooks=merge_hooks(request.hooks, self.hooks),
  File "C:\Users\Yash\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 308, in prepare
    self.prepare_body(data, files, json)
  File "C:\Users\Yash\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 496, in prepare_body
    (body, content_type) = self._encode_files(files, data)
  File "C:\Users\Yash\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 141, in _encode_files
    for (k, v) in files:
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

This happens when I try to query a model-

```
class userFiles(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(user, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    filename = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    file = models.FileField(storage=fs)
```

where the *user* model is imported from another app-

```
class user(models.Model):
    userhandle = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

The query is-

```
f = userFiles.objects.get(filename=nameToBeSearched)
```

I have tried passing the foreign-key model both as a string and as a class, based on similar questions but both give the same error.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

filename is not a unique filed in your model, so you have to use filter.
try this:

```
f = userFiles.objects.filter(filename=nameToBeSearched)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your models should start with an uppercase letter. Try to rename the user model to User

Answer (score 0):

The issue turned out to be unrelated to django.